# what does this c# lambda expression do

Tags: c#, lambda

`__value => AsOfDate = __value, AsOfDa`

AsOfDate is just a class member variable  and the whole thing is blazor auto generated code

`__builder.AddAttribute(15, "ValueChanged", (object)(global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<global::System.DateTime>>(global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<global::System.DateTime>(this, global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, __value => AsOfDate = __value, AsOfDate)))));`

Comment: It's assigning `__value` to `AsOfDate`.  Recall that a lambda expression is just a delegate under the hood, so this is a reference to a delegate that makes the assignment when it is called.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm confused about this part: AsOfDate = __value, AsOfDate; this does not seem like a normal assignment.

Comment: Your eyes are parsing the code incorrectly. "`, AsOfDate`" is not part of the lambda. There are 3 arguments being passed to `CreateInferredEventCallback`, and those are "`this`", "`__value => AsOfdate = __value`", and "`AsOfDate`".